# dynamic column in tableau based on quick filter selection

Tags: tableau-api

I would like to know if it is possible to create a dynamic column in Tableau that will change based on quick filter selection.

Example:

[Tableau sample screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xRKlR.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Try using parameters to select the category. [This will give you step by step directions.](https://www.ryansleeper.com/how-to-let-users-choose-measures-and-dimensions-in-tableau/)

Comment: Data in the column used for filtering is dynamic hence I cannot use the parameters. Any chance this could be done with just parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Doing this is as simple as it looks.

Assuming that you're using a query to fetch data, make sure the column on which you want to apply filter is available in the `select` statement.

Next, go to `Sheets` and drag the field into `Filters` section, right click on it and select `Show filter`

The filter will be visible on the right pane and can be used to alter the data depending upon the values / ranges selected.

Also, filters on Tableau give you a host of options to select from - dropdowns, radio buttons, check boxes, sliders etc etc...